# Blazor Server App suddenly throws Javascript Error

Tags: javascript, blazor

My Blazor Server App just began to throw this error when I try to run it in the VS Test Server.  It throws this error if I click the "https" button at the top of the VS IDE, however if I right-click on the Project and choose View>View In Browser it runs fine.

The code display shows some sort of javascript that formats out to be some 5877 lines of code I did not write, thus have no idea how to debug.

The Code Path when copied returns this:

> ^ScriptDocument31 blazor.server.js

This is what the error looks like in the Code Window:

[image: Image of error in Code Window]

I managed to expand the window and then saw this:

[image: DOMException]

I opened the Debugger in the Browser and see this, which confirms the issue is in the Blazor.server.js file and thus is way outside my skill set:

[image]

If any further information is needed, please state specifically what I need to present, as I have absolutely no idea what to do now or what is important in debugging this because it is not in my code.

What happened, and what do I need to do to resolve this?

I did run VS Updates and it still happens.  What else might I try?

> RangeError: Offset is outside the bounds of the DataView
> Stack trace:
> at DataView.getInt8 ()
> at https://localhost:7008/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:97869
> at https://localhost:7008/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:97943
> at https://localhost:7008/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:135243

Comment: you could try to search for test! . The error suggests that there is a invalid selector somewhere in the code.

Comment: @jeb: I have no idea where to do this search, as the code that crashes is in the blazor.server.js file and is not my code.  I really am lost here because the error is in what I consider a black box.

Comment: I added a screenshot of what I see in the console.  I searched for 'test' and the word does not appear in the code.  I am dead in the water with a deadline of May 22 and no way to meet it.

Comment: I have No idea. i would try to Clear the browser cache and cookies and then restart the browser.
Try to rebuild the project and then run it again.
Try to run the project on a different browser or device to see if the issue persists. Comment Out Code Till the Error is gone.
If none of the above steps work, you can try to create a new Blazor Server project and then copy the code over to the new project to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: I have done all the things you mentioned except for the last one, which is what I have started thinking I need to do.  However, my experience with Blazor has not been good, it seems incredibly fragile.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error, google didn't really help me but I found this . However in the end I tried what jeb suggested and created a new project and copied things one after the other (luckily it wasn't that much since the error came pretty early in the project).

But after I copied all the code the new project was still running fine, which was good on the one hand, but didn't help finding the source of the error. Then I remembered one thing I hadn't done in the new project and that was renaming the project in the Visual Studio explorer (with F2 and afterwards correcting the includes). And that was the action that led to the error I had before. When I undid the renaming the project was working fine again.

So I still have no idea why the error occured, but at least I know how to avoid it. If this helps someone to explain the error in total I would be happy to know.

Comment: Interesting.  I may have renamed something, I will have to investigate.  Thanks!